# Mean of histograms in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr, histogram

I have some data that looks like this

```
library(tidyverse)

exp.total = 2
days.total = 5
devs.total = 5
pts = 10

set.seed(1)

df <- tibble(
  exp = rep(LETTERS[1:exp.total], each=devs.total*days.total*pts),
  day = rep(1:days.total, times=devs.total*exp.total*pts),
  dev = rep(1:devs.total, each=days.total*pts, times=exp.total),
  area = rpois(exp.total*days.total*devs.total*pts, lambda = 4)
)
```

I'm trying to create a histogram where the `x` axis is bins of `area` and the `y` axis is the mean of a `count`.

I know I can count the occurrences in each area per `exp`, per `day` for all `dev` by doing:

```
df %>% 
  count(exp, day, area)
```

What I can't figure out is how to get the mean count of each area bin per `exp`, per `day` and plot that.

**Update 1**
Additionally I’d like to add error bars that represent the variability in the counts that were used to generate the means used to generate each bar.

**Update 2**
To clarify, the facets should be `day`.  `exp` should be the `fill` so that there are 2 bars per bin in this example.

**Update 3**
The following seems to get me close but I can't figure out how to adjust the number of bins using `geom_bar()`

```
df %>% 
  count(exp, day, area) %>%
  group_by(exp, area, day) %>%
  summarize(mean_area_count = mean(n)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=area, y=mean_area_count, fill = exp)) + 
  geom_bar(stat = 'identity',
           width = 0.5,
           position = "dodge") + 
  facet_wrap(~day)
```

[image]

Trying `geom_histogram()' gives me an error that both` x`and`y` can't be defined.

```
 ggplot(aes(x=area, y=mean_area_count, fill = exp)) + 
  geom_histogram(bins=10, position = 'dodge')
```

Changing `x=area` plots the raw area and not the mean_area count.
`x=mean_area_count` doesn't seem to make sense.

Hope this makes sense.  Happy to revise the question if it's not clear.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT to group by area instead of by exp:

Is this what you're looking for?

```
df %>%
  count(exp, day, area) %>%
  group_by(area, day) %>%
  summarize(mean_area_count = mean(n), .groups = "drop") %>%
  ggplot(aes(area, mean_area_count)) +
  geom_col() +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = 0:10, minor_breaks = NULL) +
  facet_wrap(~day)
```

[image]

Comment: I don’t think so.  I’ve been fooling with exp as the fill.  There should be bins of area the x axis

Comment: revised -- more like it?

Comment: I think this is closer but there should be 2 bars per bin level.  One for each `exp`.  Also, how does one adjust the number of bins?

Comment: These bars reflect each of the area values directly -- no binning actually. It might help if you could sketch what you are looking for...

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution with ggplot's `geom_bar` and `stat = "summary", fun.y = "mean"` arguments to calculate the mean. Here I had to create the bins by hand using `cut`. I am not aware of a straightforward way of plotting a histogram where the bins are chosen automatically and instead of count or frequency, you get other statistics such as the mean.

```r
library(tidyverse)

exp.total = 2
days.total = 5
devs.total = 5
pts = 10

set.seed(1)

df <- tibble(
  exp = rep(LETTERS[1:exp.total], each=devs.total*days.total*pts),
  day = rep(1:days.total, times=devs.total*exp.total*pts),
  dev = rep(1:devs.total, each=days.total*pts, times=exp.total),
  area = rpois(exp.total*days.total*devs.total*pts, lambda = 4)
)
df
#> # A tibble: 500 x 4
#>    exp     day   dev  area
#>    <chr> <int> <int> <int>
#>  1 A         1     1     3
#>  2 A         2     1     3
#>  3 A         3     1     4
#>  4 A         4     1     7
#>  5 A         5     1     2
#>  6 A         1     1     7
#>  7 A         2     1     7
#>  8 A         3     1     5
#>  9 A         4     1     5
#> 10 A         5     1     1
#> # … with 490 more rows

df %>% 
  mutate(
    area_cut = cut(area, seq(min(area)-1, max(area+1), by =2))
  ) %>% 
  count(exp, day, area_cut) %>%
  group_by(exp, area_cut, day) %>%
  summarize(mean_area_cut_count = mean(n)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=area_cut, y=mean_area_cut_count, fill = exp)) + 
  geom_bar(stat = 'identity',
           width = 0.5,
           position = "dodge") + 
  facet_wrap(~day)
```

[[image: plot]

Another way would be calculating all statistics before hand and then plotting them straight either with `ggplot` or `graphics::plot`.

#### session info

```r
- R version 4.0.5 (2021-03-31)
- ggplot2: 3.3.3
- dplyr: 1.05
```

Comment: Interestingly I'm getting the following `No summary function supplied, defaulting to mean_se()
Warning message:
Ignoring unknown parameters: fun.y `

Comment: Interesting, likely we have different versions of ggplot. See edits with my session info. You can also try `stat_summary(fun = "mean", geom = "bar")` instead of `geom_bar(...)`.

Comment: you might be able to create your bins with `scale_x_binned()` (https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/scale_binned.html)